# Sitecore 301 Redirect using MVC

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

We are rebuilding an existing legacy system using MVC4 and Sitecore 7. We however would still like to keep some legacy pages (.chm files which have been bookmarked). I would like to do a 301 redirect of some of these pages using MVC4 in Sitecore.

I googled around and found that in just MVC this could be achieved using this article "http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/04/ASPNET-MVC---Legacy-Url-Routing.aspx"

However,  I am struggling to find how the 301 Redirect would fit in Sitecore MVC implementation ?

If experts could help by providing steps needed to achieve this with pseudo code, that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many URLs are we talking about? You could just use the [URL Rewrite module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Comment: We want to make it extensible. We determined that ASP.NET routing is the way to go. But we are struggling to incorporate that within MVC in Sitecore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Sitecore 301 Redirect Module that can do that: http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/301_Redirect_module.aspx

If you need source code, that's here: 
https://github.com/thecadams/301RedirectModule

Comment: How would that utilize ASP.NET routing, since we are using MVC in Sitecore?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use Web Forms with Sitecore or MVC with Sitecore. All routing is done via Sitecore content items. This module is agnostic as it looks at an incoming path and matches against a 301 redirect item. In the context of Sitecore, there is no "routing" as Sitecore handles it for you.

Comment: There's no reason it should not. It's agnostic. It's a class that runs in the HttpRequestBegin pipeline.

Comment: I used the new 301 Redirect module at https://github.com/thecadams/301RedirectModule and it works fine on Sitecore 7.1. Thank you Mark!